# How to disable plesk 12.0.18 update notifications (especially for wordpress and for customers)

Tags: wordpress, notifications, updates, plesk

Every customer gets - on a server managed by plesk 12.0.18 -  every day wordpress update notifications (theme, plugin, etc.. ).

After upgrade to plesk 12.0.18 I can not find a disable button anywhere. Can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to "Tools&Settings->Notifications" and configure next notifications:

APS application updates (administrator's digest)
APS application updates (reseller's digest)
APS application updates (customer's digest)